# Taylor expansion of $ \arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+x)$, $ x\rightarrow0$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the method to calculate the Taylor expansion of $ \arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+x)$, $ x\rightarrow0$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for the cosine of a difference yields
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(\pi/4-y)
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(y)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(y)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sin(y)+\cos(y)-1)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Noting that $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sin(y)+\cos(y)-1)$, it is easy to show that 
$$
2\sqrt{2}x+2x^2=\sin(2y)\tag{2}
$$
Now the series for $\sin^{-1}(x)$ can be gotten by integrating the series for $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Using the binomial theorem, we get
$$
(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{4^k}\tag{3}
$$
Integrating $(3)$, we get
$$
\sin^{-1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{4^k}\tag{4}
$$
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(4)$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+x\right)
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-y\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(2\sqrt{2}x+2x^2)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{(2\sqrt{2}x+2x^2)^{2k+1}}{4^k}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}(\sqrt{2}x+x^2)^{2k+1}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
To get $2n$ terms of the Taylor series for $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+x\right)$, you only need $n$ terms of $(5)$.

**Afterthought:**

A nicer series, that doesn't involve all the $\sqrt{2}$s would be
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}(x+\tfrac{1}{2}x^2)^{2k+1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

As already noted by robjohn, it is nicer to consider $\arccos\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)  = \frac{\pi}{4} + \delta(x)$. By simple differentiation:
$$
   \delta^\prime(x) = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x - x^2}} = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n P_n(-i) x^n
$$
The last equality follows from the generating function for the sequence of [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). Hence
$$
  \arccos\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{i^n P_n(-i)}{n+1} x^{n+1}
$$

Verification:

```
In[151]:= 
ArcCos[(1 + x)/Sqrt[2]] + O[x]^51 == 
 Pi/4 - Sum[I^n LegendreP[n, -I]/(n + 1) x^(n + 1), {n, 0, 50}] + 
  O[x]^51

Out[151]= True
```

Comment: Bernoulli, Legendre, Euler; I should sit down and learn more about these polynomials.  Well done! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [List of Maclaurin series of some common functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions). And [here](https://planetmath.org/TaylorSeriesOfArcusSine) is how to obtain the Taylor series for $f(x) = \arcsin x$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge1$, we have
\begin{align}
\biggl[\arccos\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}+x\biggr)\biggr]^{(n)}
&=-\left[\frac1{\sqrt{1-\Bigl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}+x\Bigr)^2}\,}\right]^{(n-1)}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k \Biggl[1-\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}+x\biggr)^2\Biggr]^{-1/2-k} B_{n-1,k}\biggl(-2\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}+x\biggr), -2, 0, \dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&\to-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k 2^{1/2+k} B_{n-1,k}\biggl(-\frac2{\sqrt{2}\,}, -2, 0, \dotsc,0\biggr), \quad x\to0\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k} 2^{1/2+k} (-2)^k B_{n-1,k}\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}, 1, 0, \dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k-1)!! 2^{1/2+k} \frac{1}{2^{n-k-1}}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac1{2^{(2k-n+1)/2}}\\
&=-\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n/2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k-1)!! \frac{2^{k+1}}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k-1},
\end{align}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
\arccos\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{2}\,}+x\biggr)
=\frac{\pi}4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k-1)!! \frac{2^{k+1}}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k-1}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n}.
\end{equation}

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
3. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
4. Feng Qi and Miao-Miao Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.